# Chrome Click&Clean - Not clean?

Tags: google-chrome

After running Chrome Click&Clean (set to clean everything), it turns out that the SQLITE3 file .config/google-chrome/Default/Cookies is still about 250K in size.  This is huge compared with the initial size of Cookies after deleting the file and restarting Chrome.

Am I missing something.....or does Click& Clean actually NOT DO MUCH CLEANING?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't do a hell of lot, clears up a lot but not all.

Ccleaner should definitely clean that out, but be aware that cleaning up can cause error logs in registry sometimes from things badly coded trying call things which don't exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You would not expect the physical file size to change when data is removed as that would require a full rewrite of the database to disk which would be extremely inefficient. The size will not change until the browser decides to do some housekeeping (`VACUUM`). CCLeaner can compact chrome databases on demand.